# Mobile analytics tracking between custom keyboard + companion app

Tags: ios, ios8, custom-keyboard, ios8-extension, mobile-analytics

Is there a mobile analytics library for iOS that supports being used in a custom keyboard extension out of the box?

Many I have looked at so far reference `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` which is not available in application extensions, or the library has not been brought up to date for use in this context.

Would be great if I could also associate a 'session' in the companion app with keyboard usage.
Is there a provider that does this well so far?

*Note - this is purely for collecting data to improve the use of the app & keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Parse.com analytics works well just from custom keyboards. Of course full access needed for network.

Comment: Are there any tricks for setting up analytics in a custom keyboard with Parse.com? I tried and am not seeing events appear in my dashboard.

Comment: We used core data, not events, as I remember